# how to add a new table row using netbeans ide

Tags: swing, netbeans, jtable

I have created a JTable in NetBeans IDE. I want to add a new row to the table when the user gets to the lower right-hand corner of the table and presses the TAB key. I have tried NetBeans IDE options of changing the property for keyPressed, keyReleased and keyTyped, but nothing happens. Here is what I tried.

```
private void tblInterestIncomeKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)                                             
{                                                 
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB)
      {
        System.out.println("Released tab key");
        model.addRow(new Object[]
          {
            ""
          });
        System.out.println("Got to this point");
      }
}
```

I am trying to teach myself. I have seen other suggestions on this website, but they don't pertain to NetBeans IDE GUI creation. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Swing components use `Key Bindings` to bind a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`. The default `Action` for the `Tab` key is to move to the next cell. So you will need to create a custom `Action`.

You can create the custom `Action` by extending `AbstractAction` and adding your logic to the actionPerformed() method. You would then need to replace the current key binding to map to your own Action. Check out [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for example code on how to replace the bindings.

Or you can check out [Table Tabbing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/). This uses a wrapper class to help make the key bindings process easier so all you need to implement is the logic in the `actionPerformed()` method.

This example shows how to replace the default `Tab Action` with a custom `Action` that will only tab to cells that are editable. You would need to customize this Action to add a new row to the `TableModel`.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how I would accomplish this within NetBeans GUI Design window?

Comment: @schlenwkad, I never use an IDE because you spend time learning the IDE and not Java. When you switch to a different IDE the code won't be maintainable by the new IDE. Learn how to write your own code. The IDE should just be used as a debugging tool.